# UITextView text not updating

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I have UIWebview for display article. I need to select some text and send to another viewcontroller UITextView. But when i install the app i select text and it loads to  viewcontroller1. But then i select another some text when i go to viewcontroller1, the previous text only showing. It's not updating new text.

code:

viewcontroller:

```
NSString *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:selection forKey:@"preferenceName"];
    [userData1 synchronize];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller1 animated:YES];
```

viewcontroller1:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];
 [self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: what is the value of savedValue?

Comment: while launch the app savedValue coming, after that it's not coming.

Comment: when i get selection NSLog, it's updating. but NSUserdefaults is not getting the updating value. NSLog(@"selection is %@",selection);

Answer (score 0):

in your viewcontroller1 try to do it like this

```
NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedValue = [userData1 valueForKey:@"preferenceName"];

textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: It's not working. Im thinking because of this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller1 animated:YES]; having problem

Comment: make sure that you have data in your "selection" string object?

Comment: yes. this line NSString *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSString *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

    NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setValue:selection forKey:@"preferenceName"];
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller1 animated:YES];
```

//View controller

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               valueForKey:@"preferenceName"];
 UITextView *textView = [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame : cgRectMake(0,0,200,50)]//if not created textview 
 [self.view addSubview:textView];
 textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];
```

Comment: No, It's not working...If i use UIAlertview for get text it's changing, when i use NSUserDefaults it's not chaning..

Comment: is the string gives you NULL when getting the value from userdefault?

Comment: when i get selection NSLog, it's updating. but NSUserdefaults is not getting the updating value. NSLog(@"selection is %@",selection);

Comment: just try one thing NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               valueForKey:@"preferenceName"]; use the same thing in same view where you are setting the value and nslog the saved value .what u get?

Comment: yes It's working. But the problem is it's not updating to another viewcontroller.

Comment: grt so its not a problem of user default ,now NSlog the saved value of viewcontroller

Comment: May be the problem of this line this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller1 animated:YES];

Comment: i mean just NSLog this value in viewcontroller1:  NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               valueForKey:@"preferenceName"];

Comment: In viewcontroller1 it's not passing the values. When i launch app first time it passing, the come back to viewcontroller and select text pass to viewcontroller1 is not working

Comment: May be the problem is an viewcontroller1